# Set Timeout Length Python Splunk SDK

Tags: python

How do I set a timeout length for my connection with Splunk through Python with the splunklib.binding class?

Answer (score 0):

From the Splunk docs (http://docs.splunk.com/DocumentationStatic/PythonSDK/1.0/binding.html)

splunklib.binding.handler(key_file=None, cert_file=None, timeout=None)

where

- timeout (integer or “None”) – The request time-out period, in seconds (optional)

Answer (score 0):

```
    import splunklib.client as client
    import splunklib.results as results
    import splunklib.binding as binding

    port = '8089'
    host = 'foo.splunkcloud.com'
    username=self.SPLUNKUSERNAME,
    password=self.SPLUNKPASSWORD,
    connectionHanlder = binding.handler(timeout=4)
    service = client.connect(host=host, port=port, password=password, usesrname=username,handler=connectionHanlder)
```